# Error when click back navigation

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have three Activity linked intent ( Activity A intent-->Activity B(intentA+intentB) --> Activity C) I using parent Activity in Manifest.... problem when press back navitaion or Call button cancel beget error NullPointerException : Activity B(intentA+intentB). But i press back device no problem.

Please help me !

**Sorry ! I speak english very bad :(**

Code Acitivity A

```
package com.example.musicquality;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.Play.SongAdapter;
import com.example.Utils.NetworkUtils;
import com.example.Utils.Utils;

public class SongActivity extends Activity {

    public ArrayList<String> mSong = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> linkSong = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> linkImage = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) "
            + " AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16";
    public String changeLink;
    private String linkIntent;
    final String selectLinkPlay = "div#downloadlink a";
    final String afterChangeLink = "";
    private String select = ".txtsp1";
    private String url = "http://chiasenhac.com/mp3/vietnam";
    public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lvSong;
    private String nameSong;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ImageView image;
    private int positionId;
    private Intent intentData;
    private ImageButton btnSearch;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.song_layout);
        if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            new loadDataGet().execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SongActivity.this, "Please check internet access !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
            finish();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public class loadDataGet extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, Vector<ArrayList<String>>> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Vector<ArrayList<String>> result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            lvSong = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSong);
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivIconSong);
            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSong);
            tvTitle.setSelected(true);
            btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnseachbox);
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(SongActivity.this,
                    R.layout.listsong_layout, R.id.tvNameSong, R.id.ivIconSong,
                    mSong, linkImage);
            lvSong.setAdapter(adapter);
            lvSong.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    positionId = position;
                    nameSong = (String) lvSong.getItemAtPosition(positionId);
                    linkIntent = linkSong.get(position);
                    intentData = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            PlayMusicActivity.class);
                    intentData.putExtra("namesong", nameSong);
                    intentData.putExtra("data", linkIntent);
                    startActivity(intentData);
                }
            });
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SongActivity.this, "", "Loading...");

        }

        @Override
        protected Vector<ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            Vector<ArrayList<String>> data = new Vector<ArrayList<String>>();
            try {
                String urlImage = "http://chiasenhac.com/mp3/vietnam/";
                mSong = (ArrayList<String>) Utils.getInfo(data, select,
                        linkSong, mSong, url).get(0);
                linkSong = (ArrayList<String>) Utils.getInfo(data, select,
                        linkSong, mSong, url).get(1);
                linkImage = (ArrayList<String>) Utils.getLinkImages(urlImage,
                        linkImage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Server has problem... Please while for minutes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return data;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_action, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_share:
            return true;
        case R.id.action_setting:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Code Activity B(intentA+intentB) and Activity C here

Activity B(intentA+intentB). I using Asynctask. And start activity C when click download button

```
public class startNewActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String selectDoc = "div.gen img";
        private String attr = "title";
        private String resultOfLyric;
        private String result = "";
        public String Quality;
        private String getQuality;
        private String checkQuality;
        private String checkSupportDownload;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                lyric = Utils.testGetLyric(link, useReplace, resultOfLyric);
                getQuality = Utils.getQuality(link, selectDoc, attr, result);
                Quality = getQuality.substring(0, 5);
                checkQuality = getQuality.substring(5).replace(" ", "");
                changeLink = link.replace(".html", "_download.html").substring(15)
                        .replaceFirst("", "http://download")
                        .replace("nhac-hot", "mp3".concat("/vietnam/v-pop"));
                dataGetPlayAndDown = Utils.getLinkPlay(selectLinkPlay,
                        changeLink, dataGetPlayAndDown);
                urlDataSource = dataGetPlayAndDown.get(0);
                linkDownload = dataGetPlayAndDown.get(1);
                checkSupportDownload = Utils.checkSupportDownload(changeLink,
                        result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Server has problem... Please while for minutes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return urlDataSource;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            playSong(urlDataSource);
            tvLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLink);
            edTLyric = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edTLyric);
            tvTotalTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeofSong);
            tvCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeIsPlay);
            btnDownload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtDownload);
            rad32kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad32Kb);
            rad128kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad128Kb);
            rad320kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad320Kb);
            rad500kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad500);
            if (Quality.equals("32kb ")) {
                rad32kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (Quality.equals("128kb")) {
                rad128kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (Quality.equals("320kb")) {
                rad320kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (Quality.equals("500kb")) {
                rad500kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (checkQuality.equals("3")) {
                rad500kb.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (checkQuality.equals("3-256k")) {
                rad500kb.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (checkQuality.equals("2")) {
                rad500kb.setEnabled(false);
                rad320kb.setEnabled(false);
            }
            tvLink.setText(nameSong);
            edTLyric.setText(lyric);
            btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            **// Intent Here**
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            DownloadActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("download", linkDownload);
                    intent.putExtra("fileName", nameSong);
                    intent.putExtra("checkSupport", checkSupportDownload);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayMusicActivity.this, "",
                    "Please wait...");
            intent = getIntent();
            link = intent.getStringExtra("data");
            **// I think nameSong nullpointer**
            nameSong = intent.getStringExtra("namesong");
            **//When press back Navigation. Log cat give error null pointer here**
            useReplace = nameSong.substring(0, nameSong.indexOf("-"));

        }
    }
```

Activity C ( Download Activity )

Code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download_layout);
        PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        imgDownload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
        imgCancel = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        radDown128kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radDownload128Kb);
        radDown320kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radDownload320Kb);
        radDown500kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radDownload500);
        radDownLoss = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radDownloadFlac);
        tvSupport = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSupportSize);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        linkdownload = intent.getStringExtra("download");
        titleName = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
        fileName = titleName.concat(".mp3");}
```

Button Cancel.

```
imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent backActi = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        PlayMusicActivity.class);
                startActivity(backActi);
                DownloadActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Android Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.musicquality.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Song Activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.example.musicquality.SongActivity" />
        <!-- List Activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.example.musicquality.PlaylistActivity" />
        <!-- Singer Activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.example.musicquality.SingerActivity" />
        <!-- PlayMusic Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.musicquality.PlayMusicActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.musicquality.SongActivity" />
        <!-- Download Activity -->
        <activity android:name="com.example.musicquality.DownloadActivity" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.musicquality.PlayMusicActivity"/>
        <!-- Search Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.musicquality.SearchActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.musicquality.SongActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Logcat

```
07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): Process: com.example.musicquality, PID: 1654
07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicquality/com.example.musicquality.PlayMusicActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.example.musicquality.PlayMusicActivity$startNewActivity.onPreExecute(PlayMusicActivity.java:272)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at com.example.musicquality.PlayMusicActivity.onCreate(PlayMusicActivity.java:68)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

07-23 02:44:30.136: E/AndroidRuntime(1654):     ... 11 more
```

I'm newbie Android. Code of me not good :(. Please ! Reply as soon as possible

Edit

```
   package com.example.musicquality;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.Utils.Utils;
public class PlayMusicActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        OnCheckedChangeListener, OnPreparedListener {

    private MediaPlayer mPlay;
    private int LenghData;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private ImageButton btnPlay;
    private String link;
    private String nameSong;
    private TextView tvLink;
    private TextView tvTotalTime;
    private TextView tvCurrentTime;
    private RadioButton rad32kb;
    private RadioButton rad128kb;
    private RadioButton rad320kb;
    private RadioButton rad500kb;
    private ImageButton btnDownload;
    private String changeLink;
    private String useReplace;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    final String selectLinkPlay = "div#downloadlink a";
    private String urlDataSource;
    private RadioGroup group;
    private String ifChangeCheck;
    private String lyric;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private EditText edTLyric;
    private ArrayList<String> dataGetPlayAndDown;
    private String linkDownload;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playmusic_layout);
        new startNewActivity().execute();
        group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void playSong(String urlData) {
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        seekBar.setMax(99);
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPlay = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlay.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlay.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mPlay.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        try {
            mPlay.setDataSource(urlData);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Error when Seekbar don't set value or value = 0
    private void primaryUpdateSeekBar() {
        seekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mPlay.getCurrentPosition() / LenghData) * 100));
        if (mPlay.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long totalDuration = mPlay.getDuration();
                    long currentDuration = mPlay.getCurrentPosition();
                    tvTotalTime.setText(Utils.getTimeString(totalDuration));
                    tvCurrentTime.setText(Utils.getTimeString(currentDuration));
                    primaryUpdateSeekBar();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPlay.isPlaying()) {
            mPlay.stop();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
        tvTotalTime.setText("00:00");
        tvCurrentTime.setText("");
        try {
            playSong(ifChangeCheck);
            mPlay.prepareAsync();
            mPlay.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mPlay.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.seekBar) {
            SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) view;
            int playPositioninMiliseconds = (LenghData / 100)
                    * seekbar.getProgress();
            mPlay.seekTo(playPositioninMiliseconds);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnPlay) {
            try {
                mPlay.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            LenghData = mPlay.getDuration();
            if (!mPlay.isPlaying()) {
                mPlay.start();
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
            } else {
                mPlay.pause();
                btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
            primaryUpdateSeekBar();
        }
    }

    public class startNewActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String selectDoc = "div.gen img";
        private String attr = "title";
        private String resultOfLyric;
        private String result = "";
        public String Quality;
        private String getQuality;
        private String checkQuality;
        private String checkSupportDownload;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                lyric = Utils.testGetLyric(link, useReplace, resultOfLyric);
                getQuality = Utils.getQuality(link, selectDoc, attr, result);
                Quality = getQuality.substring(0, 5);
                checkQuality = getQuality.substring(5).replace(" ", "");
                changeLink = link.replace(".html", "_download.html")
                        .substring(15).replaceFirst("", "http://download")
                        .replace("nhac-hot", "mp3".concat("/vietnam/v-pop"));
                dataGetPlayAndDown = Utils.getLinkPlay(selectLinkPlay,
                        changeLink, dataGetPlayAndDown);
                urlDataSource = dataGetPlayAndDown.get(0);
                linkDownload = dataGetPlayAndDown.get(1);
                checkSupportDownload = Utils.checkSupportDownload(changeLink,
                        result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Server has problem... Please while for minutes",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return urlDataSource;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            playSong(urlDataSource);
            tvLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLink);
            edTLyric = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edTLyric);
            tvTotalTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeofSong);
            tvCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeIsPlay);
            btnDownload = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtDownload);
            rad32kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad32Kb);
            rad128kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad128Kb);
            rad320kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad320Kb);
            rad500kb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad500);
            if (Quality.equals("32kb ")) {
                rad32kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (Quality.equals("128kb")) {
                rad128kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (Quality.equals("320kb")) {
                rad320kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (Quality.equals("500kb")) {
                rad500kb.setChecked(true);
            }
            if (checkQuality.equals("3")) {
                rad500kb.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (checkQuality.equals("3-256k")) {
                rad500kb.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (checkQuality.equals("2")) {
                rad500kb.setEnabled(false);
                rad320kb.setEnabled(false);
            }
            tvLink.setText(nameSong);
            edTLyric.setText(lyric);
            btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            DownloadActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("download", linkDownload);
                    intent.putExtra("fileName", nameSong);
                    intent.putExtra("checkSupport", checkSupportDownload);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    PlayMusicActivity.this.finish();
                }
            });
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayMusicActivity.this, "",
                    "Please wait...");
            intent = getIntent();
            link = intent.getStringExtra("data");
            nameSong = intent.getStringExtra("namesong");
            useReplace = nameSong.substring(0, nameSong.indexOf("-"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.rad32Kb:
            String aftercheck32 = "";
            int checkLinkIsPlay32 = urlDataSource.lastIndexOf("/") - 3;
            String subString32 = urlDataSource.substring(checkLinkIsPlay32);
            if (subString32.contains("128")) {
                aftercheck32 = urlDataSource.replace("/128/", "/32/").replace(
                        ".mp3", ".m4a");
            } else if (subString32.contains("320")) {
                aftercheck32 = urlDataSource.replace("/320/", "/32/").replace(
                        ".mp3", ".m4a");
            } else if (subString32.contains("m4a")) {
                aftercheck32 = urlDataSource.replace("/m4a/", "/32/");
            }
            ifChangeCheck = aftercheck32;
            try {
                if (mPlay != null) {
                    mPlay.stop();
                    mPlay.reset();
                }
                playSong(ifChangeCheck);
                mPlay.setLooping(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rad128Kb:
            try {
                if (mPlay != null) {
                    ifChangeCheck = urlDataSource;
                    mPlay.stop();
                    mPlay.reset();
                }
                playSong(urlDataSource);
                mPlay.setLooping(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rad320Kb:
            String aftercheck320 = "";
            int checkLinkIsPlay320 = urlDataSource.lastIndexOf("/") - 3;
            String subLink320 = urlDataSource.substring(checkLinkIsPlay320);
            if (subLink320.contains("/32")) {
                aftercheck320 = urlDataSource.replace("/32/", "/320/").replace(
                        ".m4a", ".mp3");
            } else if (subLink320.contains("128")) {
                aftercheck320 = urlDataSource.replace("/128/", "/320/");
            } else if (subLink320.contains("m4a")) {
                aftercheck320 = urlDataSource.replace("/m4a/", "/320/")
                        .replace(".m4a", ".mp3");
            }
            ifChangeCheck = aftercheck320;
            try {
                if (mPlay != null) {
                    mPlay.stop();
                    mPlay.reset();
                }
                playSong(ifChangeCheck);
                mPlay.setLooping(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.rad500:
            String aftercheck500 = "";
            int checkLinkIsPlay500 = urlDataSource.lastIndexOf("/") - 3;
            String subLink500 = urlDataSource.substring(checkLinkIsPlay500);
            if (subLink500.contains("/32")) {
                aftercheck500 = urlDataSource.replace("/32/", "/m4a/");

            } else if (subLink500.contains("128")) {
                aftercheck500 = urlDataSource.replace("/128/", "/m4a/")
                        .replace(".mp3", ".m4a");
            } else if (subLink500.contains("320")) {
                aftercheck500 = urlDataSource.replace("/320/", "/m4a/")
                        .replace(".mp3", ".m4a");
            }
            ifChangeCheck = aftercheck500;
            try {
                if (mPlay != null) {
                    mPlay.stop();
                    mPlay.reset();
                }
                playSong(ifChangeCheck);
                mPlay.setLooping(true);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mPlay != null) {
            mPlay.start();
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_icon);
        } else {
            mPlay.pause();
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
        mPlay.start();
        primaryUpdateSeekBar();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, post the whole code of PlayMusicActivity and DownloadActivity.

Comment: What are the real names of Activity A and Activity B?

Comment: I process on Asynctask is mainly. I think when back activity i need intent vice versa PlayMusicActivity

Comment: @AndreaMotto PlayMusicActivity and DownloadActivity.

Comment: Please, post the whole code of PlayMusicActivity.

Comment: You wrote Activity C = DownloadActivity, so Activity B can't be DownloadActivity.

Comment: Oh no. I'm sorry! SongActivity - PlayMusicActivity - DownloadActivity. But error occurs in two PlayMusicActivity and DownloadActivity

Comment: @AndreaMotto i post post the whole code of PlayMusicActivity above

Comment: remove the line super.onBackPressed()

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi i remove. But don't work :(

Comment: You forgot all import parts. Please, post the whole code of PlayMusicActivity.

Comment: Sorry. But i think this no necessary

Comment: It is necessary because the real error is: "at com.example.musicquality.PlayMusicActivity$startNewActivity.onPreExecute(PlayMusicActivity.java:272)", but I don't know what you wrote in the line 272 if you don't put the import parts.

Comment: @AndreaMotto Sorry :) i update import. Please check above Error 
useReplace = nameSong.substring(0, nameSong.indexOf("-"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see:

```
link = intent.getStringExtra("data");
nameSong = intent.getStringExtra("namesong");
```

But I can't find:

```
intent.putExtra("data", "...");
intent.putExtra("namesong", "...");
```

Edit imgCancel.setOnClickListener:

```
imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent backActi = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
            PlayMusicActivity.class);
        backActi.putExtra("data", linkdownload);
        backActi.putExtra("namesong", titleName);
        startActivity(backActi);
        DownloadActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But they miss inside the imgCancel.setOnClickListener

Comment: imgCancel i have post above ? you do not see...
imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent backActi = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        PlayMusicActivity.class);
                startActivity(backActi);
                DownloadActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }

Comment: You didn't put backActi.putExtra("namesong", nameSong); and backActi.putExtra("data", linkIntent);